# Track swipe on top of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, swipe, google-dfp

I want to be able to close an ad when a user swipes on the ad.

The ad is from AdSense or DFP, i.e. dynamically created `iframes` from external hosts.

It doesn't seem possible to capture the click event of an `iframe` when the content is from another domain. There is a `iFrameTracker` plugin using the blur event, but I'm not sure if this can be used for swipe - https://github.com/finalclap/iframeTracker-jquery.

Any help in achieving this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't care about IE you may be able to do some magic with `pointer-event` and a floating div with some javascript.

Comment: Have you tried adding a transparent `<div>` over the top of your iframe?  You can handle the drag events yourself and pass any "click" events through to the iframe so the ad works.

Comment: How is it possible to pass click to cross-domain iframe?

Answer (score 2):

We were able to accomplish this by creating a transparent div above the ad, and set the height depending on touch or swipe. And it now works as expected, i.e swiping will close the ad, touch will be passed through to our iframe ad served from the ad server.

```
//Create our swipe-div
  swipeAdEl = main.x("div", {"id": "swipeAdEl"}).appendTo(this.el);

  //This will check if we have focus on the tab and give the swipe area 100% height after clicking on an ad
  var lastFired = new Date().getTime();
  setInterval(function() {
      now = new Date().getTime();
      if(now - lastFired > 1000) {
          $(swipeAdEl).css('height', '100%');
      }
      lastFired = now;
  }, 500);

}

this._googleAds.on('got-ad', function() {
      self.el.remove_class("hidden");
      $(swipeAdEl).css('display', 'block');
      $(swipeAdEl).css('height', '100%');
    });

swipeAdEl.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
  $(swipeAdEl).css('height', '0');
}, false)


    swipeAdEl.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
  self.hide();
}, false)
```

Comment: Can this behavior be applied in case of mouse?